# How to plot the $\varepsilon$-pseudospectrum of a matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix, linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. The $\varepsilon$-pseudospectrum of $A$ is the set
$$\sigma_{\varepsilon}(A)=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C} \middle| \|(A-zI)^{-1}\|\geq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right\}.$$
If, for some $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $A-zI$ is not invertible (that is $z$ is an eigenvalue of $A$), we put $\|(A-zI)^{-1}\|:=\infty$. So the spectrum is always contained in the pseudospectrum. The norm here is the operator norm or induced norm of a matrix (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)).

I would like to plot the level sets
$$\left\{z\in\mathbb{C} \middle| \|(A-zI)^{-1}\|=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right\}$$
for various values of $\varepsilon>0$ and given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ of large order $n$.

There is a package called [EigTool](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/pseudospectra/eigtool/) for MATLAB which works nicely. However, I did not find anything similar for *Mathematica*. Is there any (hopefully straightforward) way to effectively plot the level sets in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I still haven't gotten around to implementing the Arnoldi-based algorithm of [Toh and Trefethen](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0917002), so what follows is straightforward, but not very efficient code for visualizing $\varepsilon$-pseudospectra:

```
mat = ExampleData[{"Matrix", "WEST0067"}];

With[{c = Norm[mat], n = Length[mat]}, 
     DensityPlot[-c Log10[First[
                 SingularValueList[mat - (x + I y) IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray],
                                   -1, Method -> "Arnoldi", Tolerance -> 0]]],
                 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"]]
```

[image: pseudospectrum of sparse matrix]

Compare with the "spectral portrait" [here](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/Harwell-Boeing/chemwest/west0067.html).

---

It is quite easy to modify the code above to use `ContourPlot[]` instead of `DensityPlot[]`, since all that matters is the plotting of the (logarithm of the) greatest singular value of the resolvent matrix $(\mathbf A-\lambda\mathbf I)^{-1}$ (equivalently, the least singular value of its inverse). Here's the example used in the [EigTool download page](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/pseudospectra/eigtool/download/):

```
(* Grcar matrix, https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2390 *)
grcar[r : _Integer?Positive : 3, n_Integer?Positive] := 
     SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; j == k + 1 :> -1, {j_, k_} /; 0 <= k - j <= r :> 1}, {n, n}]

mat = grcar[32]; eigs = Eigenvalues[N[mat]];

With[{c = Norm[mat], n = Length[mat]}, 
     ContourPlot[-c Log10[First[
                 SingularValueList[mat - SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> x + I y, {n, n}],
                                   -1, Method -> "Arnoldi", Tolerance -> 0]]],
                 {x, -2, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                 Contours -> Range[1, 6, 1/2], ContourShading -> None,
                 ContourStyle -> Black,
                 Epilog -> {Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]], Point[ReIm /@ eigs]}]]
```

[image: pseudospectral contours for Grcar matrix]

Coloring and other sundry styling is left to the interested reader.

Comment: Notes: 1. The matrix norm (`c` in the code above) is merely a scaling factor, and can be left out if desired. 2. Jeff Bryant did some previous work [here](http://members.wolfram.com/jeffb/visualization/west0655.shtml).

Comment: Thanks, this utility is pretty useful! One question, how do I plot them for specific values of epsilon? Right now I'm seeing contours being larger than numeric range, confused which epsilon this corresponds to -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-pseudospectra.nb

Comment: @Yaroslav, if you look at the second formula given in the OP, and compare with the form I used here, you would need to feed `{-c Log10[ε]}` into `Contours` to get the contour line for a particular value of `ε`.