# Visualizing pseudo-spectra of large matrices

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, visualization

I'm looking to reproduce some pseudo-spectra figures on Mark Embrees' site https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/pseudospectra/random/dense.html

In particular, a pseudo spectrum of a random square matrix with $N=1000$:

[image]

The code below, [borrowing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136379/217) from JM can plot pseudospectrum for N=10 matrix, but doesn't scale to $N=1000$, any tips?

```
spectrumPlot[mat_, eps_] := 
  With[{c = Norm[mat], n = Length[mat]}, eigs = Eigenvalues[mat];
   ContourPlot[-c   Log10[
      First[SingularValueList[
        mat - SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> x + I   y, {n, n}], -1, 
        Method -> "Arnoldi", Tolerance -> 0]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
     2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> {eps}, 
    ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Black, 
    Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
      Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]], Point[ReIm /@ eigs]}, 
    PlotLabel -> "pseudospectrum"]];
n = 20;
mat = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[n]], {n, n}];
spectrumPlot[mat, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Please, pay attention that `Circle[{0, 0}, 1]` is not shown in your picture.

Answer (score 3):

Matrix `mat` we test with this code is dense one, therefore, "Arnoldi" is not appropriate method. With Automatic options we have

```
spectrumPlot[mat_, eps_] :=

With[{c = Norm[mat], n = Length[mat]}, eigs = Eigenvalues[mat];
   ContourPlot[-c    Log10[
      First[SingularValueList[
        mat - SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> x + I  y, {n, n}], 
        Tolerance -> 0]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> {eps}, 
    ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Black, 
    Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
      Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]], Point[ReIm /@ eigs]}, 
    PlotLabel -> "pseudospectrum"]];

n = 2^10;
mat = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[n]], {n, n}];
spectrumPlot[mat, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Figure 1]